# Repeat switch statement until it is valid

Tags: loops, dart, if-statement, switch-statement

```dart
import 'dart:io';

//Week days
enum WeekDays {
  Monday,
  Tuesday,
  Wednesday,
  Thursday,
  Friday,
  Saturday,
  Sunday,
}

void main() {
  print("Enter the number from 1-7");
  int? WeekDayNumber = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  switch (WeekDayNumber) {
    case 1:
      print("Monday");
      break;
    case 2:
      print("Tuesday");
      break;
    case 3:
      print("Wednesday");
      break;
    case 4:
      print("Thursday");
      break;
    case 5:
      print("Friday");
      break;
    case 6:
      print('Saturday');
      break;
    case 7:
      print('Sunday');
      break;
    default:
      print("Please re-enter your number");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To repeat things, you want a loop.

Dart has three loop constructs, `for` (really two: `for(;;)` and `for( in )`), `while(){}` and `do{}while();`

You can use a loop condition and set it to exit the loop when you have found a good answer, or you can just use an always-true condition and exit using `break`.

In this case, you always want to run at least once, so I'd use a `do`/`while` with a condition variable:

```dart
bool success = false;
do {
  print("Enter the number from 1-7");
  int? WeekDayNumber = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  switch (WeekDayNumber) {
    case 1:
      print("Monday");
      success = true; // <-- sets loop condition on success.
      break;
    // ...
    default:
      print("Please re-enter your number");
  }
} while (!success);
```

If using break, where the condition isn't used, I'd use `while (true)` as the canonical "loop forever". Other languages favor `for(;;)`, but Dart users seems to prefer `while (true)`, probably because it reads better:

```dart
loop: // <- label for the loop, so you can break it from inside switch.
while (true) {
  print("Enter the number from 1-7");
  int? WeekDayNumber = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  switch (WeekDayNumber) {
    case 1:
      print("Monday");
      break loop;  // <-- exits loop directly on success.
    // ...
    default:
      print("Please re-enter your number");
  }
}
```

(You likely meant to use `int.tryParse` instead of `int.parse`, since you expect a nullable result).

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Irn, and it worked for me, wanna give you five stars but I can't find any feature on this platform.